How to replace a math character, like S in txfonts?
The problem is seemingly very strange, but in txfonts math letter S has bad kerning. It adds horizontal interval of about +1.5pt. For example $S_gT$ generates:

I've tried this code without success:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\originalS}{\mathcode`S}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`S
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\originalS\!}
\mathcode`S="8000
\makeatother


Welcome to TeX SE. What do you want to achieve? Could you expand the code to make it compilable?

You did not say what you intended the code to do, I guess you wanted it to do this, although it seems a strange thing to want?

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtx}

\makeatletter
\mathchardef\originalS\mathcode`S
\begingroup\lccode`~=`S
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\originalS\!}
\mathcode`S="8000
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$RSTU$

\end{document}


Dear, David! Thank you very much! Your code works for me very well!

Indeed, with
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

$S_gT$

\end{document}

the output is what you show: txfonts is known for bad kerning and it's generally recommended not to use it.
Let's replace txfonts with newtx:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtx}

\begin{document}

$S_gT$

\end{document}

to get

I don't think this requires “fixing”. A possible improvement would be to increase the \scriptspace:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtx}

\setlength{\scriptspace}{1pt}

\begin{document}

$S_gT$

\end{document}


If you insist in using txfonts, you can set a kern for subscripts in a letter-by-letter fashion:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\NewDocumentCommand{\genericfixkerning}{mme{_^}}{%
  \UseName{original#1:}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{_{\mspace{#2mu}#3}}%
  \IfValueT{#4}{^{#4}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fixkerning}{mm}
 {% #1 = character, #2 = amount of mu
  \exp_args:Nc \mathchardef {original#1} = \char_value_mathcode:n {`#1}
  \cs_new:cn {xheng_#1:} { \use:c {original#1} \genericfixkerning {#1} {#2} }
  \char_set_active_eq:nc {`#1} { xheng_#1: }
  \char_set_mathcode:nn {`#1} { "8000 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\fixkerning{S}{-3}

\begin{document}

$S_gT_gU$

$S_g^2 S^2_g T_g U$

\end{document}


Here S needs a kern for subscripts

Dear egreg! Thank you very much for such detailed explanations in so many aspects. I would give you upvote if I didn't have a poor reputation.
